# write concatenated scss and compiled css to distribution folder with webpack

Tags: reactjs, webpack

We package React components as Node modules with Webpack (https://github.com/tocco/tocco-client). These modules shall self-contain all individual styles as a css-file for instant usage and as a scss-file for theming.

**file structure before Webpack compilation**

```
package-1/
    dist/
    src/
        component-a/
            component-a.js
            component-a.scss
        component-b/
            component-b.js
            component-b.scss
```

**desired file structure after Webpack compilation**

```
package-1/
    dist/
        package-1.js  /* contains component-a.js and component-b.js */
        package-1.css  /* contains component-a.scss and component-b.scss */
        package-1.scss  /* contains component-a.scss and component-b.scss */
    src/
        component-a/
            component-a.js
            component-a.scss
        component-b/
            component-b.js
            component-b.scss
```

With Webpack loaders it is possible to write package-1.css or package-1.scss, but not both files in a single run. It seems that all loaders with the same "test-pattern" are combined in a single task pipe.

Following implementations are based on https://github.com/webpack/extract-text-webpack-plugin

**instaces of plugin**

```
let extractSASS = new ExtractTextPlugin('index.scss')
let extractCSS = new ExtractTextPlugin('index.css')
```

**Example 1: causes an error, because css-loader is rendered twice**

```
webpackConfig.module.loaders.push(
    {
        test: /\.scss$/,
        loader: extractSASS.extract('css-loader')
    },
    {
        test: /\.scss$/,
        loader: extractCSS.extract('css-loader!sass-loader')
    }
)
```

**Example 2: causes no error but only writes a css file**

```
webpackConfig.module.loaders.push(
    {
        test: /\.scss$/,
        loader: extractSASS.extract('css-loader')
    },
    {
        test: /\.scss$/,
        loader: extractCSS.extract('sass-loader')
    }
)
```

**Example 3: causes no error but only writes a scss file**

```
webpackConfig.module.loaders.push(
    {
        test: /\.scss$/,
        loader: extractSASS.extract('css-loader')
    }
)
```

**Example 4: causes no error but only writes a scss file**

```
webpackConfig.module.loaders.push(
    {
        test: /\.scss$/,
        loader: extractCSS.extract('css-loader!sass-loader')
    }
```

)

**Questions:**

1. Is it possible to generate an output in the middle of a loader pipe?
2. Is it possible to generate an ouput per separateley defined loader, like it is intended with configuration "Example 1"?
3. Does Webpack demand a certain implementation for generating several outputs of one filetype (having several scss files and wanting one scss file and one css file)?

Comment: may be `extractCSS.extract(['style', 'css', 'sass'])`

Comment: Thank you free-soul. Style-loader injects CSS into DOM by a style tag. I am searching for a configuration to generate several output files of one stream. I would like to save the output of sass-loader as file.scss as well as passing on the same output to css-loader to save that output as file.css.

Comment: May I can not accomplish the outlined goal in section "desired file structure after Webpack compilation" by loaders. Probably I have to use "chunks", "multiple entrypoints" or another concept of Webpack?

Comment: As far as I understand your question, I could achieve your goal after I did some tweaks on your [`webpack.config.js`](https://github.com/tocco/tocco-client/blob/master/build/webpack.config.js). But to be sure, I need more clarification as I think I am missing your context. 1. Do you want 2 bundles, one `index.scss` and another with the same code converted to css as `index.css`? 2. As opposed to doing the above, why do you need a separate `index.scss` file when you cannot load it in your HTML (the MIME type doesn't exists).

Comment: could you please tell me why we need a `.scss` file?

Comment: I intend to create 2 bundles (index.css and index.scss) like you have noted above by point 1. Index.css only contains default stylings like standard colors and typography. All components of monorepo tocco-client get packaged as single components and can be included in other applications. This other applications get the ability to restyle all components conveniently by scss to match different corporate designs. The entrypoint for restyling will be [Theme.scss] (https://github.com/tocco/tocco-client/blob/pr/webpack-separate-styles-from-js/packages/tocco-ui/src/Theme/Theme.scss).

Comment: The currently discussed webpack configuration ist only used for first compilation in the monorepo. A second compilation in a third-party-application is not planned to implement here.

Comment: We have decided not to concatenate files. For environment ENV wie use style-loader, css-loader and sass-loader. For distribution on NPM (environment PROD) we copy scss files to dist folder (https://github.com/tocco/tocco-client/blob/master/build/webpack.config.js).  Default Styling is in https://github.com/tocco/tocco-client/tree/master/packages/tocco-theme/src/ToccoTheme . To ensure correct import of distinct package styles we create a virtual file https://github.com/tocco/tocco-client/blob/master/build/mutable-scss-imports.js . This file also has to be generated on targeted system.